# How to call the Search bar from homepage to all other pages in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, local.xml

My **Search bar** is currently on my **[Homepage](http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/)**

Code is:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I want to make the search bar appear on my [New products Page](http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/newproducts)

Comment: <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topSearch’) ?> in template you can call like this

Answer (score 2):

in your local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="core/template" name="product.view.search" as="productViewSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

then in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` add call children

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('productViewSearch') ?>
```

Comment: yes first of all, dont mind to asking here brother, i will remove these comments surely. but there is one editor for formatting the content. thats y i used to be the content in better view. you rejected that chance also.